Adapt vert.x HttpClient to Feign AsyncClient
The last working feign-vertex version is 2 years old, and newer versions seem broken.
I'm trying to use Feign AsyncClient directly.
This is what I came up, unfortunately I'm not getting a response.
The code doesn't look to complex so most likely the problem is when converting to CompletableFuture?
object : AsyncClient<Unit> {
    override fun execute(
        request: Request,
        options: Request.Options,
        optional: Optional<Unit>
    ): CompletableFuture<Response> {
        return httpClient
            .request(
                RequestOptions()
                    .setMethod(HttpMethod.valueOf(request.method()))
                    .setURI(request.url())
                    .setHeaders(request.headers().toCaseInsensitiveMultiMap())
            )
            .compose(HttpClientRequest::send)
            .compose { Future.all(Future.succeededFuture(it), it.body()) }
            .map { composition ->
                val response = composition.resultAt<HttpClientResponse>(0)
                val body = composition.resultAt<Buffer>(1)
                Response
                    .builder()
                    .status(response.statusCode())
                    .headers(response.headers().associate { it.key to listOf(it.value) })
                    .body(body.bytes)
                    .build()
            }
            .toCompletionStage()
            .toCompletableFuture()
    }
})


There might be some information missing in your Vert.x RequestOptions object. For example, if the remote port is not 80, you will have to specify it. If the server is running TLS (HTTPS), you will have to specify that, too.

The .compose { Future.all(Future.succeededFuture(it), it.body()) } part is a bit complicated. Instead use .compose { response -> response.body.map { body -> ... In that inner closure you can access response and body.

Finally, Feign's Response needs the Request object before it can be successfully built. Make sure to add that.
